# how to supress the below banner,Authentication (publickey) successful! and Connected version 2.0, client OpenSSH_6.6.1 on Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

My function to perform ssh using `paramiko` and and log file will be generated with below info.

```
def node():
    ssh=paramiko.SSHClient() 
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    ssh.connect(SelfIP,SSHport)
    stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command('ls -lrt')
    outlines=stdout.readlines()
    resp=''.join(outlines)
    cmd = "exit"
    print("RESP",resp)
    logging.info(resp)

node()
```

How do we suppress or make sure the below lines should **not** appear in log file, any suggestions?

```
2019-03-18 15:30:41,226 INFO Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_6.6.1)
2019-03-18 15:30:41,444 INFO Auth banner:
Attention! Unauthorized remote access is strictly prohibited!

2019-03-18 15:30:41,445 INFO Authentication (publickey) successful!
```

Comment: basically the objective is to the above messages should not appear in Log file .

Comment: can anybody look into the above requirement?

Comment: kindly let me know about the above query

Comment: Python experts waiting for some response.

Comment: Change the logging level to warning? Possibly only for paramiko.